# WSO2 Identity Server cannot handle IdP initiated logout with special SP names

Tags: wso2, saml, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

It seems that WSO2IS does not honor the special characters in spEntityID parameter such like:

https://wso2is.localnet:9443/samlsso?spEntityID=http://otherhost/&RelayState=http://otherhost/logout.jsp

Do you have any idea how to sort this out? The SP cannot be set to use different issuer. The UrlEncoding doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if the the SP doesn't send to WSO2IS IdP the SessionIndex in the SAML2 LogoutRequest, it fails since cannot get it from it.

*This answer was posted by OP (toma) as a separate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870838/wso2-identity-server-requires-sessionindex-in-logoutrequest-saml-message), I've just pasted it here to get evertyhing in one place.*